# In JSP,I entered a Float value into a Form.How could I access it from the Action page as Float?

Tags: jsp

In JSP,I entered a Float value into a Form.how could i access it from the Action page as Float value?

Answer (score 1):

`Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("value"))` should work..